# get value after dash in Get Cookie in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Im getting the value of cookie,

**Issue :** in value after dash only that has to be printed, example below :

> Key : agc
>
> value : @MALLAPS-MCO

By trying out the below code im getting complete value "**@MALLAPS-MCO**" instead of only **MCO**

**JS :**

```
 function getCookie(name){
        var pattern = RegExp(name + "=.[^;]*")
        matched = document.cookie.match(pattern)
        if(matched){
            var cookie = matched[0].split('=')
            return cookie[1]
        }
        return false
    }
```

Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 2):

your [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with `=` only gets you till value **"@MALLAPS-MCO"**, you need to [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it again, as:

```
function getCookie(name){
    var pattern = RegExp(name + "=.[^;]*")
    matched = document.cookie.match(pattern)
    if(matched){
        var cookie = matched[0].split('=')
        //split "@MALLAPS-MCO" again using "-" as delimiter
        return cookie[1].split("-")[1];
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it troughs some Error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'

Comment: @undefined see updated answer, it should be cookie[1].split(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this using just one regex:

```
function getCookie(name){
    var pattern = RegExp(name + "=.[^;]*")
    matched = document.cookie.match(pattern)
    if(matched){
        var pattern = ".*-(.*)"
        return matched[0].match(pattern)[1]; 
    }
    return false
}
```